# Is it possible to summon entities similar to how the fill command works?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I wish to know if it is possible to summon entities in the same way you would use the /fill command in Minecraft for example summoning a layer of arrows above the player.

I don't know if this is possible but if not is there anything similar I could do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [How do I summon a layer of entities efficiently?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/394722/how-do-i-summon-a-layer-of-entities-efficiently) (newer question, but has an actual answer)

Answer (score 1):

No you can't.

You have to define a function that records all relative positions you want the arrows to spawn. This could be done easily with code generators if you know actual programming languages.

Example:
Generate a layer of arrow matrix (5x5) below the player.
The function should look something like this.

```
execute positioned ~-2 ~-1 ~-2 run summon arrow
execute positioned ~-1 ~-1 ~-2 run summon arrow
...
execute positioned ~2 ~-1 ~2 run summon arrow
```

There should be 5x5 = 25 lines of code in total, each includes a relative coordinate to summon an arrow. If done correctly, this could do the job.

An in-game method to spawn entities in a certain pattern has not been developed and added in to the game. Even with the help of external generators, the process may be tedious and slow.