# How do I summon a layer of entities efficiently?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a system of commands where trapdoors are traps, so whenever someone holds the trap in their hand, the trap happens to everyone. I already made part of the command for the birch trapdoor:

```
execute if @a[type=player,nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:birch_trapdoor",Count:1b}}]
```

but I want it to summon a layer of falling birch logs above the player's head and cannot think of a way to do this efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I brainstormed an answer to my own question:**
Since it's a manhunt(minecraft manhunt but), it's unlikely anyone is gonna bother to make blue concrete powder. So, I will /fill blue concrete powder above everyone's head:
`execute if @a[type=player,nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:birch_trapdoor",Count:1b}}] at @a fill ~-1 ~3 ~-1 ~1 ~3 ~1 blue_concrete_powder`

If it weren't a manhunt, I would put more  effort on this and put a custom tag on it somehow, but it isn't a survival server, so it's fine.

Then, I will have a command block that run with a small delay time after the first so the concrete powder can turn into an entity:

`execute as @e[type=falling_block,nbt={BlockState:{Name:"minecraft:blue_concrete_powder"},Time:2}] data merge entity @s {Passengers:{id:"falling_block",nbt:{BlockState:{Name:"birch_log"}}}}`

Finally, we kill all blue concrete powders:

`kill @e[type=falling_block,nbt={BlockState:{Name:"blue_concrete_powder"}]`

If you don't understand what this does, it /fills a layer of blue concrete powder, lets them turn into entities as they fall, then /data merges a passenger of falling birch logs onto the falling blocks. Afterwards, the blue concrete powder is /killed, leaving the birch logs flying at the player.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I made that this command will summon an anvil at the top of their head. Just place 2 command blocks in this way.

The first command block needs to be on repeat mode and always active:

```
/execute if entity @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:birch_trapdoor",Count:1b}}] at @a[name=!PutYourNameHereAndDontDeleteTheExclamationMark] run setblock ~ ~10 ~ minecraft:damaged_anvil
```

The second command block needs to be on chain mode, conditional, always active (be sure the arrows are in the same way):

```
/execute as @p[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:birch_trapdoor",Count:1b}}] run clear @s birch_trapdoor 1
```

Comment: The @a[name=!PutYourNameHereAndDontDeleteTheExclamationMark] is that the trap doesn't work on yourself and only works on other players, So you won't get hurt.

Comment: Thank you, but I looked for a a layer of falling birch, not anvils. I found a better way, though. Nice pfp btw.

Comment: But if you try with summoning birch log falling blocks, It doesn't do any damage at all.

Comment: You can make them deal damage using the FallHurtAmount NBT tag. By the way, I have resolved my issue, so you can look at my solution now.